# Can't get data from my express server api?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My localhost http://localhost:3001/read is an API which is working but in my front end I can not get any data from the API:

my express app.js

```
app.get('/read', async (req, res) => {
Diary.find({}).exec((err, data) => {  //Diary is my mongodb collection
if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
if (data) res.status(200).send(data)
})
})
```

my frontend using react js:

```
useEffect(() => {
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/read").then((data)=>{
console.log(data)
}).catch((e)=>{
console.log(e)
})
})
```

Result: GET http://localhost:3001/read 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Are you sending 400 on erred find and also on successful find? That's odd.
On successful find, you'res supposed to send status 200

Comment: Omg that worked wow. Didn't know status code also matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.js should be

```
app.get('/read', async (req, res) => {
 Diary.find({}).exec((err, data) => {  //Diary is my mongodb collection
  // status code for server error is 500
  if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
  // for successful request, you don't explicity need to send a status code it is 200 by default so you can do this directly
  if (data) res.send(data)
 })
})
```